# Rails association scope by method with aggregate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to retrieve association records that are dependent on their association records' attributes.  Below are the (abridged) models.

```
class Holding
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :transactions

  def amount
    transactions.reduce(0) { |m, t| t.buy? ? m + t.amount : m - t.amount }
  end

  class << self
    def without_empty
      includes(:transactions).select { |h| h.amount.positive? }
    end
end
```

```
class Transaction
  belongs_to :holding

  attributes :action, :amount

  def buy?
    action == ACTION_BUY
  end
end
```

The problem is my `without_empty` method returns an array, which prevents me from using my pagination.

Is there a way to rewrite `Holding#amount` and `Holding#without_empty` to function more efficiently with ActiveRecord/SQL?

Comment: Is `buy?` a boolean attribute on the `transactions` table?

Comment: It's not, although I suppose  it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up using:

```
def amount
  transactions.sum("CASE WHEN action = '#{Transaction::ACTION_BUY}' THEN amount ELSE (amount * -1) END")END")
end
```

```
def without_empty
 joins(:transactions).group(:id).having("SUM(CASE WHEN transactions.action = '#{Transaction::ACTION_BUY}' THEN transactions.amount ELSE (transactions.amount * -1) END) > 0")
end
```